# How to make this type of array in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Is there a way to make this kind of shape with curves in Geometry Nodes?

[image]

I had a go, but think I am just getting down a rabbit hole. For sme reason, I don't have access to the rotation of each instance. Also, I am not sure how to make the instances increase in number until they fit around the circle.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just extrude a circle?

[image]

Comment: +1 damn, that was easy! ;)

Comment: and if you want faces: https://i.imgur.com/GV8AS3L.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, but mine was with faces... It's just wireframe shading mode. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys ohhh... Makes sense now that I think of it.

Comment: I don't get it though... :D The simpler the answer, the more up-votes. You spend 1 minute on the simplest question and it gets up-voted more than the ones that take days to figure out. :D